Why is solving for a 2x2x2 tensor with specific conditions so slow?
I am trying to find the space of all 2x2x2 tensors such that on each dimension the sub tensors are orthogonal. I ran the following wolfram desktop code:
Solve[
a*Conjugate[e] + 
b*Conjugate[f] + 
c*Conjugate[g] + 
d*Conjugate[h] == 0 &&
 a*Conjugate[d] + 
b*Conjugate[c] + 
e*Conjugate[h] + 
f*Conjugate[g] == 0 && 
a*Conjugate[b] + 
d*Conjugate[c] + 
e*Conjugate[f] + 
h*Conjugate[g] == 0, 
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, Complexes]

I used 8 complex variables directly since it was easier to write out. However, I have been running it for a few days and it is still not done. Am I doing something wrong or how should I speed this up? Would writing it in tensor language make it faster? Although I do not know how to do that.

Wouldn't the most obvious answer be a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=0? But to give you an idea of the kind of thing you might expect in general, try running a much simpler version: Reduce[a * Conjugate[b] + c * Conjugate[d] == 0, {a, b, c, d}]. The answer is pretty large already.

@bills I'm trying to find the whole space of solutions so should I be using Reduce instead of Solve? Also, I have already figured out the much simpler 2d versions but I cannot see how they could be extrapolated to this.

Probably Reduce is the right command to find all the solutions. I would try starting small and add on conditions as you go since the answer is likely to be very large. Or maybe there is a way of adding constraints so you divide up the solution space.

@bills wdym by starting small and adding on conditions? Can I first solve just one equation then solve the next in the solution space of the first and so on? Or can I just get the solution space for each of the equations then find their intersection? But I presume wolfram alpha would be doing something similar or even faster than that so I don't see how this would speed it up.

But you already said that the computation was taking days. By breaking it up, you may be able to "help" Mathematica along.

@bills How would i do this breaking up? I'm fairly new to wolfram alpha still.

The use of Conjugate is good for nothing, execpt for numerics and printing. In algebraic calulations the rules for non-analytic complex valued functions generate logical expressions in tons, that simply are clogging the copy channels in memory: any new subroutine call copies the complete intermediate results into its local input variable space.
There are two ways out: Declare all symbols Real
$Assumptions=
Element[ vars=Union@Flatten@Cases[myexpression,_Symbol,\[Infinity]],
   Reals]

and don't even use imaginary 'I', but a 'J' and add the $J^2=-1$ rule as an explicit operation never to be applied internally in every step like Conjugate.
      JExpand[expr_] := 
        expr //. {J^n_?Negative :> J^(-n), J^n_?(#>=2&):>-J^(n-2)  

The other way is to treat z and Conjugate[z] = w for any symbol as two independent variables, as they are independent linear combinations of the real coordinates by adding to $Assumptions
Element[ Symbolize/@StringAppend[#,"CC"]/@ToString/@vars,Reals]


So using the first way does this work: https://pastebin.com/b9gxz34w ?
